# How do I reinstall bash in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, reinstall

bash seems to be throwing a segfault, and my system is very broken.  I was thinking of trying to reinstall bash instead of reinstalling the whole OS, but this is nontrivial apparently.  I can't use apt-get because my network connection isn't connected (apparently due to bash being broken...?)  So I booked a recovery disk and downloaded the deb file for it - but I can't do dpkg - it says this:

```
# dpkg -i bash_4.1-2ubuntu3_i386.deb
Selecting previously deselected package bash.
(Reading database ... 22385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bash 4.1-2ubuntu3 (using bash_4.1-2ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: warning: old pre-removal script killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing bash_4.1-2ubuntu3_i386.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-removal script killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bash_4.1-2ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Anybody got any advice?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: What shell type are you using to login? Can you fix the network problem first?

Comment: How do you know it's bash, and not failing hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `bash-static` to avoid dependency problems with broken libs and circumvent the removal script errors.

If this also failing with similar errors your shared libs may be broken.

The next try could be to copy `/bin/bash-static` from a live-cd to `/bin/bash` on your system.